# How can I display names by using loop with setTimeout() function

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to display members' names in the div element after 3 seconds by using for loop with `setTimeout()` function. But I'm getting an `undefined` values of the names array. And even the value of `var i` displaying 4. I don't know why. Can anyone explain to me why and how to fix that.?

Thanks in advance!

**JS Code:**

```
function members() {
  var arr = ["Joseph","John","Kumar","Shiva"];
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Member = " + i + ". " + arr[i]);
      document.getElementById("Names").innerHTML = "Member = " + i + ". " + arr[i];
    }, 3000);
  }
}
members();
```

```
<div id="Names"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Because `var` is a function scope ( not block scope like `for loop` ), when the `setTimeout` execute after 3 sec, the loop will be ended and the value of `i` will be equal to the `arr.length`, and arr[arr.lenght] will equal to `undefined`.

To solve this issue, one solution is using `let` instead of `var`.

Second, If you want to add the members to `HTML`, you need to use `+=` to concatenate with the previous `string` not `=` which will re-initialize the `innerHTML`

```js
const names = document.getElementById("Names");

function members() {
  var arr = ["Joseph","John","Kumar","Shiva"];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Member = " + i + ". " + arr[i]);
      document.getElementById("Names").innerHTML += `Member = ${(i + 1)}. ${arr[i]}<br />`;
    }, 3000);
  }
}
members();
```

```html
<div id="Names"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think better solution for you here is to execute a function after 3 seconds, rather then putting the timeout inside for loop.

That was what was causing your issue, as the `var` is a function scoped variable. So by putting timeout inside of for loop, the last element would be undefined since your script would read the last element as `arr.length`, which is 4, and you don't have arr[4], hence it is undefined.

Also, your innerHTML was not written properly, if you want to print multiple values, you need to use `innerHTML +=` instead of `innerHTML =` because `innerHTML =` will always print the last value from your loop, because it erases the innerHTML of your element in each new iteration.

I modified your code snippet below.

https://codepen.io/Juka99/pen/VwxpXwL

Comment: Yeah, I got your point. But I need that function executed only after 3 sec. Anyway thanks for the tip.!